# Populate html field using google server functions

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a gui that is bound to a Google Spreadsheet. I originally wrote the gui using the built in google buttons and other google elements.  Recently, google depreciated these API's, so I am rewriting it using html/javascript.

Here is my question: Suppose I have a html text field, and I want the gui to interact with data from a google sheet. What is the best way to do this?

For example, suppose I want to change a cell in the spreadsheet. Why does the following html NOT produce my expected change?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 function onSuccess(argReturnValue) {
alert('Success ' + argReturnValue);
}

 var data =   google.script.run.withSuccess(onSuccess).SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,14).setvalue('in HTML');
```

I Am rather new to javascript and html, so I may have some fundamental misunderstanding of how the two interact, or possibly am just using the script function wrong.

I understand that an alternative way to run some script is to use the script tag  as follows:

```
<script src= 'fileExtension.gs'></script>
```

But I am not sure with this method how to fill html text fields.

Thanks in advance for the help, even if it is just pointing me to a tutorial about this, or an API that I need to read.

Answer (score 0):

The code you mentioned is using apps script (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/).
Here you can find the documentation on how to make those kind of calls: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication

when calling the method  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)     .doSomething();

this function will call the function "doSomething" defined in your ".gs" file. Then the server will execute that function and return the results.

With this function you can call the functions you defined in your ".gs" file but not the services for apps script, this means the call to SpreadsheetApp or other service won't work.

If you are not using apps script, here you can find the documentation in the Spreadsheets api: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

hope it helps.

Comment: This does help, thank you very much.  I have some reading to do, but just to clarify, when you say "With this function you can call the functions you defined in your ".gs" file but not the services for apps script, this means the call to SpreadsheetApp or other service won't work."  do you mean I can not call App scripts from the html? Or that the .gs file can not perform services for apps?

Comment: In apps script "service" means the API ... so if you want to use GMail API functions you would use the GmailApp service to do it.  in the functions you declare in your .gs file is where you can make calls to these services like the SpreadsheetApp service. From the html you can call your own functions but not the services as you posted in your code.  Also the html will need to bi linked to the apps script project: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/   let me know if it's still not clear